# Deleting referencing side entity in @ManyToMany relationship: JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I am working on a Spring Boot Project in which I have used a **Many TO Many** relationship between two entities- **User** and **Category**.
**For User-**

```
//Set of categories a user is following
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    @JoinTable(name = "user_category", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id",              
                    referencedColumnName = "id"),          
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(                
                    name = "category_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "categoryId"))
    private Set<Category> categories=new HashSet<>();
```

**For Category-**

```
// set of users who follow the category
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories",cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

**What I want-**
When I delete a **User** only user should be deleted and not the **Category**.
When I delete a **Category** only category should be deleted and not the **User**.
**Problem-**
When I delete a **User**, it gets deleted successfully without affecting category. But, when I delete a **Category**, I get an error-

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog_application_database`.`user_category`, CONSTRAINT `FK4x6ipr43cfvhqc3aqda6j8c2l` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`))
```

Now, to remove the associated users, in the category I use-

```
 @PreRemove
    public void removeUsers() {
        System.out.println("Removing users for " + this.categoryName + " before deleting");
        this.users=null;
        this.users=new HashSet<>();
    }
```

But, the problem is not resolved.

- One approach I came across from several other posts was to manually remove each and every mapping from each user (from user side) but it would be highly inefficient.
  I am adding a screenshot of the db tables-
  [image]
  Please help me understand what is going wrong here and how to resolve it.

Comment: `user_category` has an actual FK on the `category_id` in the database it seems. Is the same the case for the `user_id`?

Comment: I have added a screenshot for better understanding. user_category table holds the P.K. of user and category for Many to Many relationship.

Comment: The screenshot does not show any constraints? Or at least not that I can tell

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `Category#users` collections has no effect on the relationship, because that is not the owning side of it. The owning side is the one which has no use of `mappedBy`.

So if you want to remove a category, you will first have to remove the category from every `User#categories` collection.

Maybe it's easier if you don't map that relationship as a `@ManyToMany` association and instead introduce an entity for the join table. Then you can use `@OneToMany` on both sides with `DELETE` cascading.

Answer (score 1):

your entity Category should :

1. remove all association from its Users;
2. override hashCode() and equals() functions properly;

```java
class Category{
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", ...)
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    @PreRemove
    public void removeUsers() {
        users.forEach(user->{
            user.getCategories().removeIf(e->e.equals(this));
        });
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Category)) return false;
        Category category = (Category) o;
        return getId() != null && getId().equals(category.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(Category.class);
    }
}
```

it is suggested to put the deletion inside transaction, or otherwise you may end up with Exception like "Multiple representations of the same entity"

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
void deleteCategory(Long id) {
    Category category = categoryRepository.findById(id);
    categoryRepository.delete(category);
    log.info("deleted --> {}", category);
}
```